# Where do I put geckodriver.exe on a webhost

Tags: python, selenium, geckodriver

Is it possible to use selenium to scrape a page on a webhost?  I have a virtualenv with Python and Selenium installed.  I have tried:

```
driver = webdriver.FireFox()
```

but I get this...`Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.`

I downloaded geckodriver.exe and put it into a directory and tried:

```
driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/home/user1/public_html/gecko/geckodriver.exe")
```

but I get this...`OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error`

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide path of directory, which contains geckodriver.exe

```
driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/home/user1/public_html/gecko")
```

Comment: This helped, but now I get two exceptions: `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied` in service.py and `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'gecko' executable may have wrong permissions. ` in my python script.  I had the permission set to 755, and even tried 777

Comment: Can you try to put geckodriver in different path?